# Rest API with Java socket Server

Tags: java, android, rest, sockets, server

I would like to create an Android game and it would be a turn by turn game. To do that i wanted to a java Rest API for everything that concern the users (log/disconect account, change account settings, etc..). And I also wanted to do a Java socket server for the game itself. I don't know exactly where to start because I have some unanswered questions. Do I need two differents servers ? like one for the rest API and another for the java game ? Is there other (good) way to do it ? At first I wanted to go with websocket but it is aparently not really stable.

Thanks for your reading.

Comment: Seems too broad to be a good fit for stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question : No you do not need two Servers.

If I was planning something like this I would do the following :

1- For the API I would use spring restful api because it is based on java so in the end you will end up with a java program that you need to run on a server.

2- The Game Engine socket can be a simple java app and you run it on the same server doesn't matter as long as you keep the firewall open for that port.

I would prefer to use something like Tomcat to run my java applications both the API and the Game Engine.

More info about Tomcat:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat

This is a simple example/tutorial provided by spring:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Comment: Ok. So I'll just need to have another port for my java socket app ?

Comment: @kingy yes the Restful api should be on port 80 but that will be done by default in spring so you should keep in mind that this port will be used for API interactions. Next you have the game engine port which should have a different port number and you open the port in the firewall of that Server so you can accept connections.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need two differents servers ? like one for the rest API and another for the java game ?

You can provide both functions with just one server, but if your game gets viral, you'll need more servers to supply all the demand it could have.

> Is there other (good) way to do it ?

A broad question... if you implement artificial intelligence in your game, you won't need any server.

> At first I wanted to go with websocket but it is aparently not really stable.

Are you sure? What tells you so?

A piece of advice: REST, sockets and websockets are somewhat different technologies from one another. They are modelled for different domains and addresses different problems. I suggest you to study further each one of these before designing your game architecture.

Comment: Not really stable for the android client. Didn't find a perfect stable one yet. My game is not going to run on a browser so I'm going to go with the socket solution.